# Covariant generics with an operator?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, covariance

Is there any way to have this class's generic argument be covariant while keeping the operator?

```
public class ContentReference<T> where T : IReferable
{

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ContentReference(T value)
    {
        this.Name = value.Name;
    }        

    public static implicit operator ContentReference<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ContentReference<T>(value);
    }

}
```

So that I can have, say, a `ContentReference<Audio>` be assigned to by a `ContentReference<SoundEffect>` or `ContentReference<MusicTrack>`?

Comment: Since only interfaces (and delegates) can be covariant, the answer is no. Perhaps if you explain more of what you're _wanting_ to do (and why_ an alternative can be provided.

Comment: On what @DStanley wrote, I'll add: only interfaces can be covariant/contravariant. Only classes/structs can have operators (because they are static methods)

Comment: Whoops hit wrong button. I'll clarify my exact situation.

Comment: @xanatos I stand corrected.  Comment removed.

Comment: @AlphaMCubed The response is still no :-) You could create a base `ContentReference` class, and have some `virtual` methods

Answer (score 0):

The response is no... What you can do:

```
public abstract class ContentReference
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected ContentReference(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public abstract void Play();
}

public class ContentReference<T> where T : IReferable
{
    public ContentReference(T value) : base(value.Name)
    {
    }        

    public static implicit operator ContentReference<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ContentReference<T>(value);
    }

    public override void Play()
    {
        // Play the IReference 
    }
}
```

So the solution is that you can have a base class (optionally `abstract`) that exposes the common methods that are partially implemented in the base class and partially implemented in the subclass(es).

Or you could define a contravariant `IContentReference<out T>`:

```
public interface IContentReference<out T> where T : IReferable
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class ContentReference<T> : IContentReference<T> where T : IReferable
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ContentReference(T value)
    {
        this.Name = value.Name;
    }

    public static implicit operator ContentReference<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ContentReference<T>(value);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
IContentReference<Audio> interf1 = new ContentReference<SoundEffect>(new SoundEffect());
IContentReference<Audio> interf2 = new ContentReference<MusicTrack>(new MusicTrack());

IContentReference<Audio> interf3 = (ContentReference<SoundEffect>)new SoundEffect();
IContentReference<Audio> interf4 = (ContentReference<MusicTrack>)(new MusicTrack());
```